# Material-Table React. How to make the table Title and Header sticky

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, material-ui, material-table

Is it possible to make the table title, search field, global actions icons and column headers in the Material-Table sticky?

I've tried adding headerStyle to options and that has no effect (anyway that would only affect column headers and not the table title etc)

```
options={{
        headerStyle: { position: 'sticky'},
        paging: false,
        search: false,
    }}
```

Has anyone got any ideas how to do it?

I was hoping a 'sticky header' option existed but if it does I cannot see it!
I would have thought a sticky header is a fairly common use case for tables.

This is the basic code to use a Material Table:

```
import React from 'react';
import MaterialTable from 'material-table';

export default function MaterialTableDemo() {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    columns: [
      { title: 'Name', field: 'name' },
      { title: 'Surname', field: 'surname' },
      { title: 'Birth Year', field: 'birthYear', type: 'numeric' },
      {
        title: 'Birth Place',
        field: 'birthCity',
        lookup: { 34: 'İstanbul', 63: 'Şanlıurfa' },
      },
    ],
    data: [
      { name: 'Mehmet', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 1987,     
birthCity: 63 },
      {
        name: 'Zerya Betül',
        surname: 'Baran',
        birthYear: 2017,
        birthCity: 34,
      },
    ],
  });

      return (
<MaterialTable
  title="Editable Example"
  columns={state.columns}
  data={state.data}
  editable={{
    onRowAdd: (newData) =>
      new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          resolve();
          setState((prevState) => {
            const data = [...prevState.data];
            data.push(newData);
            return { ...prevState, data };
          });
        }, 600);
      }),
    onRowUpdate: (newData, oldData) =>
      new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          resolve();
          if (oldData) {
            setState((prevState) => {
              const data = [...prevState.data];
              data[data.indexOf(oldData)] = newData;
              return { ...prevState, data };
            });
          }
        }, 600);
      }),
    onRowDelete: (oldData) =>
      new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          resolve();
          setState((prevState) => {
            const data = [...prevState.data];
            data.splice(data.indexOf(oldData), 1);
            return { ...prevState, data };
          });
        }, 600);
      }),
  }}
/>
```

);
}
`

Comment: Could you provide an online demo? Or full code?

Comment: Hi @keikai  I've added some code to the question.  Essentially I am just using the material table demo code as above, but in my app I have also made a version that uses some of my own data and options like no paging and no search field.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out in the end:

I had to add the these to the Material Table options.  It means knowing in advance the height that you want your table to be.  I

```
  options={{
          headerStyle: { position: 'sticky', top: 0 },
          maxBodyHeight: 500,
      }}
```

and then also this was necessary to add to the Material Table depending on pagination setting:

```
  components={{
        Container: props => (
          <div style={{height: 500}}>
           {props.children} 
          </div>
        ),
      }}
```